# jquery and script files not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html file with some code and jquery and js files my problem is if that scripts files are bottom of the page its working fine but if i put that files in top of the file i mean in header tag its not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Testing</title>   
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style-default.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_color" />   
</head>
<body class="fixed-top">
/*some html code here*/

<div id="footer"></div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sparkline.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>

<!--common script for all pages-->
<script src="js/common-scripts.js"></script>

<!-- END JAVASCRIPTS -->   
</body>
</html>
```

help me out,
kiran

Comment: So, why is that a problem? Best practice puts the script files at the bottom of the page because that allows the page to load more quickly.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes you are right but problem is i have one more html page if i put these script files at bottom its not working but put it in top of the page its working fine..

Comment: Then you have some differences between the pages and some dependencies that aren't being satisfied. The question you have posted doesn't address your real problem, so work out what the real problem is and ask a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there are dependencies in the scripts on DOM elements that are not loaded yet. 
You can wrap your JavaScript in a document.ready handler if you want the scripts to be loaded in the head tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //do your JS stuff here
});
```